# MVC Model Validation Unobtrusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, validation

I'm using the jquery unobtrusive method of validating my models in the UI.  I have a numeric field in a model that I want to validate as a number.  Out of the box, it almost works correctly.  It fails on the client side when validating .33 versus 0.33.  I know that I can change regex in the jquery validation plugin, but that doesn't seem to be ideal.

So, to try to fix the issue without modding the plugin itself, I created the following validation attribute:

```
public class DecimalValidator : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute, System.Web.Mvc.IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        decimal val = 0;
        ValidationResult ret = new ValidationResult("Must be a valid decimal");

        if (decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val) )
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return ret;
    }


    #region IClientValidatable Members

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata metadata, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context)
    {
        List<System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule> ret = new List<System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule>();

        System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule validDecimalRule = new System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid decimal.",
            ValidationType = "decimal"
        };

        ret.Add(validDecimalRule);

        return ret;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And applied it like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The price per unit.
    /// </summary>
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    [DecimalValidator]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the html still renders with 
     data-val-number="The field Price must be a number." 
in addition to the new one, 
     data-val-decimal="Please enter a valid decimal."

How do I keep the default validation attributes from being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `[Range(0, double.MaxValue)]` is forcing it load the number validation.
Try adding that into your custom validator and removing it from your field decorators.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    decimal val = 0;
    ValidationResult ret = new ValidationResult("Must be a valid decimal");
    ValidationResult rangeRet = new ValidationResult(String.Format("Number must be between 0 and {0}", double.MaxValue.ToString());

    if (decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val) )
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    else if (value < 0 || value > double.MaxValue)
        return rangeRet;
    else
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: No, it is not the range validator either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be to use $.extend to replace the number validation in the plugin with the regex that allows .33 and 0.33

Comment: I'm still curious to know what is causing the validation rules to even appear on the client if you take out the `Range` decorator.  I haven't really experimented with the unobtrusive validation plugin though, only the jQuery validation plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you creating a custom validator?  MVC will validate for you by default.  If you make your type nullable (decimal?) then MVC will set UnitPrice to null if a non-decimal is entered, as well as make your model state invalid if it violates any other validation you are doing.

Comment: He said in his question why: "Out of the box, it almost works correctly. It fails on the client side when validating .33 versus 0.33."

Comment: @TerryR - But that's not true, the default model binder will parse .33 just fine, so he must be talking about something else.

Comment: Ya I didn't validate that, I just offered a solution based on what he was asking for.  At least he has two different paths to go down now...

Comment: The question states that the problem is in the client side, not the server side.

Comment: @Darthg8r - Where did I say anything about server side?  Out of the box, if you use a data type of `decimal?`, it will correctly validate .33 on both server side and client side using unobtrusive validation.  It "just works".  I have tested this.  So why are you jumping to conclusions that I am talking about server side?